# socat - Monitoring USB port to standard CP2102 serial adaptor

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, socat

I have been trying to get a HEX dump of what is being sent/received to CP2102 serial converter chip. I can find examples of people monitoring *hardware* serial ports /dev/TTYS0 and the like.

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0 pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB1,raw,echo=0
```

Does anyone know of a resource that could tell me how to monitor a USB port like this? So far nothing has worked. Maybe I just don't understand the rerouting side of serial monitoring or something?

Comment: Like I said, I am just trying to get a HEX dump of what is being sent and received through the port.

Comment: Right now I have software communicating to an external serial port. I want to monitor what is being sent and received between the two. I should have said so, sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, the easiest may be to adjust the software to emit hex. Most software will likely already have `sdio.h` (or equivalent) and hex-of-the-serial-data simply requires `printf` calls (or equivalent) on the data going to and from the serial file descriptor. No complication of an extra process ferrying the data to and fro and little extra latency.

If you're in a hurry something like `strace` (or `sysdig` `SystemTap` etc) could be used to record the communication though `strace` will slow a process down, a lot, and the output will require post-processing; the other two are kernel modules so may not be suitable.

```
strace -xx -y -e trace=read,write -p $pid_of_your_program_here
```

At the hardware level a Bus Pirate or similar may be another way to tap into the communication.

Meanwhile, `socat(1)` does appear to have a handy `-x` for hex option:

```
   -x     Writes  the  transferred  data not only to their target streams,
          but also to stderr. The output format is  hexadecimal,  prefixed
          with  ">  "  or "< " indicating flow directions. Can be combined
          with -v .
```

which after some experimentation I was able to listen in on a random Arduino via:

```
socat -x PTY,link=/dev/blah,raw,wait-slave /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Arduino...
```

and then your software could open up `/dev/blah` (or maybe instead run it via `EXEC`?). Note that no `raw` option was specified after the `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Arduino...` path as with that set there were `tcgetattr(6, ...): Inappropriate ioctl for device` errors when `socat` tried to configure it. The `socat` output will likely also require post-processing, as it looks something like:

```
--
2017/10/09 16:32:20 socat[30806] I transferred 1 bytes from 6 to 5
< 2017/10/09 16:32:20.475916  length=31 from=2042 to=2072
 52 65 71 75 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 74 65 6d 70 65  Requesting tempe
 72 61 74 75 72 65 73 2e 2e 2e 44 4f 4e 45 0a     ratures...DONE.
--
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! strace it is! I am now able to debug this crazy program...